# How to send SMS through 'Dongle' using C++

Tags: c++, qt, sms

I have a USB dongle connected to my laptop which is used to get the internet connection. No need to say it has a sim card and it is possible to send/receive SMS as well. I want to know how can I get the SMS and send SMS using my own C++ windows program, through this SIM card. Is there a way to access the SIM card and do these? Any libraries? I haven't done any USB programming anyway.

### Edit

I just found it is possible with something called "AT Commands" - [How to Auto send SMS via Broadband USB dongle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925836/how-to-auto-send-sms-via-broadband-usb-dongle)

But the link in the answer is dead. Even though it is AT Command, which lib should I install in order to use it?

Comment: That would probably depend on the make and model of the USB dongle, but I would expect any SDK from a major service provider to be private. So, what's the make and model?

Comment: "I haven't done any USB programming anyway". then you have a lot to learn. possibly you could learn about mass storage part of the USB protocol. usb.org will have information. i dont know of any windows API for USB communication but you have to use `Readfile()` and `writefile()` and such. by the way i hope you have the VID and PID?. you could get this book <http://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-Complete-Developer-27s-Guide-Guides/dp/1931448086>

Comment: @Merlin069: Huwawei IS THE DONGLE

Answer (score 0):

At (Attention) commands can be used to interact with the USB dongle. Each manufacturer has their own At-commands, so you will have to find out one which suits your model (mine was Huawei e173-u). Some of the common ones can be found in the Hayes command set :

[Hayes Command Set (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)

[Introduction to At commands](http://www.developershome.com/sms/atCommandsIntro.asp)

You will need to find out which COM port your dongle uses from the Device Manager, then use a serial-port terminal like Putty to test out whether the commands are supported by your dongle. As the libraries developed for sending SMS's are mostly for .Net, you may need to use an SMS gateway instead.